# bootstrap 5 modals on mobile with viewport tag

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

i written a web-application that uses the tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

to zoom in mobile automatically, everything works fine.

But the modals do not go to fullscreen completely any ideas how could i fix this?
Or is there another good auto-zoom-in Function on mobile?
Nothing worked i tested.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA6cf.jpg)

I tried to remove this tag, than it worked (but like on a pc screen and not on the full device size), but the side is not anymore zoomed in and i couldn`t  find a another solution for this.

Comment: Did you try setting `initial-scale=1` in the viewport?

Comment: yes, but than it is not anymore "zoomed-out"